# How to hide Picker select handle in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using `<Picker>` to select items in react-native android app. It shows a right handle for users to click. Is there a way to hide this hande or customize it?

Below is my code:

```
<Picker
        style={this.props.style}
        selectedValue={this.state.title}
        mode={Picker.MODE_DROPDOWN}
        onValueChange={(t) => this.setState({title: t})}>
        {
          this.state.titles.map((title,i) => {
            return <Picker.Item key={i} label={title} value={title}/>
          })
        }
      </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try NativeBase Picker for customize picker.

[native picker component on iOS and Android](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#picker)

Comment: In order to use native picker component, do I need to rebuilt the whole UI structure with base-native style?

Comment: @ZhaoYi No, You can use only picker component from native base module.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to remove the caret if you add the **backgroundColor** style to your picker component.

```
  <Picker
    style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}} // <---- Add backgroundColor style
    selectedValue={this.state.title}
    mode={Picker.MODE_DROPDOWN}
    onValueChange={(t) => this.setState({title: t})}>
    {
      this.state.titles.map((title,i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={i} label={title} value={title}/>
      })
    }
  </Picker>
```